# Distinguish call of `then` through `await`

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, proxy

Is there some way to distinguish a request for the `then` function (or its call) from `await`?

I would like to do something like this:

```
var myProxy = new Proxy(myPromise, {
    get: (t, k) => {
        if (k == 'then') {
            if (/* from await? */) console.log('from await')
            else console.log('without await')
        }
    }
});
```

Essentially, I need to distinguish between the following two options for calling `then`:

```
var a = await myProxy;

var b = myProxy.then(res => /* something */);
```

Comment: "*I need to distinguish*" why? Seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: additionally, `.then()` in both instances are identical. They are methods of the Promise object with nothing that uniquely identifies them.

Comment: @VLAZ To better understand how it works.

Comment: `await` shouldn't be uniquely identifiable. Not unless you try to examine the call chain, then reverse-parse the source code and try to do analysis on the call site. That's not something any sane application should ever use, though, so there is no real **need** for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, and you also should not.

You *can* distinguish a direct `then` call where the caller passes only a single argument (`await` always passes [both](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572)), and you could possibly distinguish that a user-defined function is passed not some native resolver functions. However, you can never distinguish `await value` from `Promise.resolve(value).then(…)`.

```js
(async () => {
   const thenable = {then: console.log};
   
   thenable.then();
   thenable.then(() => {});
   thenable.then(res => {}, err => {});
   Promise.resolve(thenable);
   await thenable;
 })();
```

<sub>(Btw, no reason to use a `Proxy` if all you want is to intercept a single method.)</sub>

Comment: In principle, this partially solves my task. Thus, we can assert that if at least one of the `then` arguments after `toString()` does not return `function () {[native code]}` the call to `then` originated from the user. Unfortunately, the opposite is not true as we get the same result if the user calls for example `.then(console.log, console.log)`. To completely close the task by this way, it is enough to get `"[native code]"` in the form of an array of bytes or an encoded string or the like. Is there such a possibility?

Comment: @Alex Is `fn.toString()` what you are looking for?